# Python Dictionary Comprehension into single list(s)

Tags: python

I'm just learning Python and built a product review app as a first go, but hit a problem that i can't work out how to fix from the documenation.

I have the following data that i like to re-structure.

```
data = [{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'CPU', 'Rating': 6.15}, 
{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'Grpahics', 'Rating': 5.0}, 
{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'Screen', 'Rating': 9}, 
{'Product_name': 'Macbook Pro', 'Area': 'CPU', 'Rating': 8}, 
{'Product_name': 'Macbook Pro', 'Area': 'Graphics', 'Rating': 5.0}]
```

I'd like to produce a single list for each Product containing the ratings

```
[
    ["Razor Blade 15","6.15","5.0","9"],
    ["Macbook Pro","9","8","5.0"]
]
```

I've tried:

```
super_dict = {}
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(super_dict)
```

Which almost works, but not quite:

```
{'Product_name': ['Razor Blade 14', 'Razor Blade 14', 'Razor Blade 14', 'Macbook Pro', 'Macbook Pro'], 'Area': ['CPU', 'Grpahics', 'Screen', 'CPU', 'Graphics'], 'Rating': [6.15, 5.0, 9, 8, 5.0]}
```

Is there a way i can take the data and work into the format i need?

Cheers

Comment: Try reading up on [comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/). Additionally, note that *you* defined `super_dict` as a dictionary. So, try making it a list if you want a list! (Or convert to a list after you have the dictionary of you're taking advantage of the fact that a dictionary won't duplicate values).

Comment: Yes sorry you are absolutly correct, i should have made it clear that when i try with `[]` it breaks i assume because its looking for key and value pairs. I switched to `{}` which kinda works.

Comment: How do you expect `Razor Blade 14` to become `Razor Blade 15`, and where shall its rating `9` come from?

Comment: cause if i can build that list, i wouldn't be here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```py
dict_object = {}
for datum in data:
    name = datum["Product_name"]
    rating = str(datum["Rating"])
    dict_object.setdefault(name, [name]).append(rating)
```

At this point, `dict_object` is a dictionary whose keys are the product's names and the values are what we want.

```py
{'Razor Blade 14': ['Razor Blade 14', '6.15', '5.0', '9'],
 'Macbook Pro': ['Macbook Pro', '8', '5.0']}
```

In order to get what we want, we will take only the values:

```py
result = list(dict_object.values())
```

And result is:

```py
[['Razor Blade 14', '6.15', '5.0', '9'], ['Macbook Pro', '8', '5.0']]
```

The key here is how `setdefault` works: Think of its implementation as

```py
def setdefault(dict_object, key, value):
    if key not in self:
        dict_object[key] = value
    return dict_object[key]
```

That means if the key is not in the dictionary, it will be created with `value`. Finally, the method returns the value.

## Update

In order to separate the name from the rating:

```py
dict_object = {}
for datum in data:
    name = datum["Product_name"]
    rating = str(datum["Rating"])
    dict_object.setdefault(name, []).append(rating)
result = list(dict_object.items())
```

The result then will be

```py
[('Razor Blade 14', ['6.15', '5.0', '9']), ('Macbook Pro', ['8', '5.0'])]
```

Comment: This seems to make sense to me. From this is there a way to seperate the `razor blade 14` from the scores? To end up with: 
`['razor blade 14'], ['6.15,'5.0','9'],['Macbook Pro'],[...]`

Comment: Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the data, save the rating corresponding to product name in a dictionary in a list, and then modify the dictionary result according to your final output.

```
data = [{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'CPU', 'Rating': 6.15}, 
{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'Grpahics', 'Rating': 5.0}, 
{'Product_name': 'Razor Blade 14', 'Area': 'Screen', 'Rating': 9}, 
{'Product_name': 'Macbook Pro', 'Area': 'CPU', 'Rating': 8}, 
{'Product_name': 'Macbook Pro', 'Area': 'Graphics', 'Rating': 5.0}]
 
dic = {}
for record in data:
    if record['Product_name'] not in dic:
        dic[record['Product_name']] =[]
    dic[record['Product_name']].append(record.get('Rating'))
result =[[k, *v] for k, v in dic.items() ]
print(result)
# [['Razor Blade 14', 6.15, 5.0, 9], ['Macbook Pro', 8, 5.0]]
```

Comment: That is really smart. thank you for the explaination and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure some trial and error would take you to your desired answer.

I would do the following:

1. Create a dictionary of `product name -> list of ratings`

   ```
   product_ratings = {}
   for product_data in data:
       product_ratings.setdefault(product_data['Product_name'], []).append(str(product_data['Rating']))
   ```
2. Iterate this interim dictionary to obtain the desired result

   ```
   result = []
   for product_name, ratings in product_ratings.items():
       result.append([product_name] + ratings)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Might try `itertools.groupby`:

```py
data = [
    [group, *[map["Rating"] for map on maps]]
    for group, maps in groupby(
        sorted(data, key=lambda d: d["Product_name"]),
        key=lambda d: d["Product_name"]
    )
]
```